# Maintaining unique page values per tab without session storage

Tags: session, session-cookies, session-storage

I have a site that allows editing client records.  If I’m editing clientId 1 in tab A and then begin editing clientId 2 in tab B, tab 1 is still displaying data for ClientId 1. But if I click save, the data is being stored in Client 2’s record since ClientId 2 was opened last.   How can I maintain the unique ClientId’s per browser tab? I tried assigning a unique Id per tab when a new tab is created and storing it in session storage. But the Id is lost as soon as the page navigates to the next page. Also, if the user opens a new tab using the Duplicate menu, the unique Id is duplicated for the new tab and results in 2 tabs with the same Id.